# Flash Actionscript 3 Link not open in SWF File

Tags: actionscript-3, hyperlink, flash

Software: Flash CC

I need to add a link to my swf "movie"-banner. I have watched now over 10 Tutorials but it still not work. I can click on the banner but nothing is happening.

This is my code:

```
var my_url:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("link");

import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

link.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, visit);
function visit(event:MouseEvent):void {
navigateToURL(new URLRequest ,"_blank");
}
```

I have checked the public settings too with security...

Please help me :8

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing (what's `link`, do you really use `"link"` as url, etc), and it seems like you haven't searched anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The URLRequest constructor takes a String as a parameter - the url to which you intend to navigate - so add that into the `navigateToURL(new URLRequest('url string here'), "_blank");` line and you should be fine.

If you're intending to pass in the pre-instantiated 'my_url' URLRequest, then:

```
navigateToURL(my_url, "_blank");
```

But then you would have to create that URLRequest with a more meaningful URL than the String 'link'.